# vivado hls loop unroll is sequential

Tags: vivado

I have the following loop which is part of a fully connected layer for a neural net:

```
for (int b = 0; b < batch_size; b++) {
  #pragma HLS loop_tripcount min=1 max=10
    // Output Node Iterator
    array_cpy:for (int o = 0; o < num_outputs; o++) {
    #pragma HLS loop_tripcount min=1 max=1024
      // Set bias
        small_fixedpt output_fixp;
      output_fixp = biases[o];
      //float input_sub_array[1024] = input[o*num_inputs:o*num_inputs+1024];
      small_fixedpt input_sub_array[1024] = {0};
      small_fixedpt weight_sub_array[1024] = {0};
      subcopy:for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
          input_sub_array[i] = input[b*num_inputs+i];
          weight_sub_array[i] = weights[o*num_inputs+i];
      }
      // Accumulate weighted sum
      input_loop:for (int i = 0; i < num_inputs; i++) {
      #pragma HLS loop_tripcount min=1 max=1024
          output_fixp += input_sub_array[i]*weights[i];
      }
  // Compute activation
  if(output_fixp < 0) {
      output[b*num_outputs+o] = 0;
  }
  else {
      output[b*num_outputs+o] = output_fixp;
  }
}
```

My input arrays are partitioned in a cyclic manner equal to the number of unroll factor in 'input_loop' which is 16.

However, this loop unrolls into a sequential manner, as seen from the analysis view:[image]

So i can see that my inputs are being read from seperate memory blocks.
I know that i've built an accumulator but I have also tried the method of custom creating an adder tree. That does not seem to work.

I also see 16 multipliers being made (ap_fixed is the data type used):

```
INFO: [RTGEN 206-100] Generating core module 'fc_layer_mul_mul_sc4': 16 instance(s).



INFO: [XFORM 203-501] Unrolling loop 'subcopy' (../fc_test/fc_layer.cpp:28) in function 'fc_layer' partially with a factor of 16.
INFO: [XFORM 203-501] Unrolling loop 'input_loop' (../fc_test/fc_layer.cpp:33) in function 'fc_layer' partially with a factor of 16.
INFO: [XFORM 203-101] Partitioning array 'weights.V' (../fc_test/fc_layer.cpp:8) in dimension 1 with a cyclic factor 16.
INFO: [XFORM 203-101] Partitioning array 'input.V' (../fc_test/fc_layer.cpp:10) in dimension 1 with a cyclic factor 16.
INFO: [XFORM 203-101] Partitioning array 'input_sub_array.V' (../fc_test/fc_layer.cpp:26) in dimension 1 with a cyclic factor 16.
INFO: [XFORM 203-101] Partitioning array 'weight_sub_array.V' (../fc_test/fc_layer.cpp:27) in dimension 1 with a cyclic factor 16.
```

Does anyone know what's going on? This is baffling me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HLS, Sigh!

I don't see much inherent parallelism in the way you have written this, lots of nested stuff that does not have obvious parallelism.

I would be lifting your sub arrays out and having batch_size of them then the MAC could be parellelised across batch_size DSP blocks.

Also, where is weight_sub_array used? Your MAC is using the weights array directly?

You might be writing in something almost C like, but never forget you are describing hardware, not writing sequential code.